# How to add variables from button to html output in jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am using some jQuery to generate some html, however I want to be able to dynamically populate an id field using a variable from the button I use using on click.

How do I do this in jQuery? Sorry if this is a basic question but I have started jQuery today.

**In my code I basically want the data-id element in my button to be shown in the span of generated html from the jQuery**

See here my code:

```
window.onload = function () {    
            
            jQuery(document).ready() 
            
            jQuery(function(){
                
               jQuery( ".add-pe" ).click(function() {
                
            jQuery(".values-list").append('<li><input type="hidden" name="acf[field_61e58083d6d49][]" value="1016"><span data-id="1016" class="acf-rel-item">Black t shirt<a href="#" class="acf-icon -minus small dark" data-name="remove_item"></a></span></li>');
});
            });
        };
```

```
<p><a class="add-pe btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-4" data-id="<?php echo $post_ID; ?>">Add to claim</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this using the following:

```
   window.onload = function () {    
            
            
             
            
            jQuery(document).ready() 
            
            jQuery(function(){
                
                
                
               
                
                
                
               jQuery( ".add-pe" ).click(function() {
                   
                   
                   var dataId = jQuery(this).attr("data-id")
                   var title = jQuery(this).attr("title")
                   
                   
                jQuery(".values-list").append('<li><input type="hidden" name="acf[field_61e58083d6d49][]" value="' + dataId + '"><span data-id="' + dataId + '" class="acf-rel-item">' + title + '<a href="#" class="acf-icon -minus small dark" data-name="remove_item"></a></span></li>');
});
            });
        };
```

```
<p><a class="add-pe btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-4" data-id="<?php echo $post_ID; ?>" title="<?php echo $title?>">Add to claim</a></p>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).